# Logout doesn't work

Tags: unity, login, lightdm, 16.10

When I click the logout button all the programs close, panels disappear etc. as expected but it doesn't go to the login screen, it's just stuck looking at wallpaper and mouse cursor. I've found a "workaround" to this problem by changing to a different tty and running `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`.

`journalctl -p err` shows:

```
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed    
sty 21 12:30:47 tatooine gnome-session-binary[2190]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```